# batch script set inside if statement is not working

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying compress folders using batch script with 7zip

But SET function inside if statement is not working ;(

Folders structure:

```
2000/
   01/
   02/
   03/
   04/
   05/
   06/
   07/
   08/
   09/
   10/
   11/
   12/
2001/
   01/
   02/
   03/
   04/
   05/
   06/
   07/
   ...
```

Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
echo %date%
set logMonth=%date:~4,2%
set logDay=%date:~7,2%
set logYear=%date:~10,4%
set path="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\";%path%

if %logMonth% EQU 01 (

set logMonth=12
set /a logYear=%logYear%-1
7z a -tzip c:\%logYear%%logMonth%.zip   C:\files\v2-output\%logYear%\%logMonth%

) ELSE (

rem 1 saraas busad sar bol tuhain onii umnuh sariin folderiig ziplene 
set /a logMonth=%logMonth%-1
7z a -tzip c:\%logYear%%logMonth%.zip   C:\files\v2-output\%logYear%\%logMonth%

)
endlocal
```

If current month equivalent 01 compress folder last month of previous year, else compress previous month of current year. Help guys!

Answer (score 2):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the ENTIRE block is parsed and **THEN** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **AT THE TIME THE BLOCK IS PARSED** - before the block is executed.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the chnaged value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note that any calculation performed by a `set /a` assumes that any string starting `0` is an **OCTAL** constant, hence `set /a var+=%month%` will produce an error for month=08 (August) or 09 (September) because `8` and `9` are not valid **OCTAL** characters.

Set /a suppresses leading zeroes, so `set /a var=03` will set `var` to `3`, not `03`. Classically, to calculate using a DECIMAL value with a leading zero, you'd use `set /a value=1%value% - 1` and then use [or set `value` to] `%value:~1%`

So - try

```dos
if %logMonth% EQU 01 (
 set /a logMonth=112
 set /a logYear=%logYear%-1
) ELSE (
 rem 1 saraas busad sar bol tuhain onii umnuh sariin folderiig ziplene 
 set /a logMonth=1%logMonth%-1
)
set logmonth=%logmonth:~1%
7z a -tzip c:\%logYear%%logMonth%.zip   C:\files\v2-output\%logYear%\%logMonth%
```